# iOs device-specific resources not working - ~iPad loading default XIB - universal app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, universal

I'm making a universal app based on the Utility App template.  I've selected a universal app and the MainView.xib and MainView~iPad.xib work properly on both device types.

On the iPad2, when I switch to the FlipsideView, it loads FlipsideView.xib even though there is a perfectly good FlipsideView~iPad.xib file in the project.  The default xib is normal (iPhone) sized and displaying in the lower left hand corner of the iPad.

I did have to create the FlipsideView~iPad xib manually.  I believe I have the xib properly wired in IB as it shows identical to the FlipsideView.xib connections.

Over the last couple weeks, I've read quite a few posts with similar problems and [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191472/ios-using-device-modifiers-for-loading-xib-files) answers most clearly and contains links to Apple documentation.  So I know it works for others and is documented.

The code for this section is identical to the showInfo() method in the stock Utility App template.

(Yes I realize I can manually load the ~iPad version checking UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM().  I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong in getting the ~iPad modifier to work.)

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

in the end i found the solution. it is really very very simple.
The xib must be named ~ipad instead of ~iPad, and ~iphone instead of ~iPhone.
The bad thing is the if you name them ~iPad, everything works in the simulator but it does not work on the real device.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am surprised it took me like an hour to find this! - using suffix ~iphone and ~ipad for automatic xib file selection for different device.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I had to Product -> Clean in xCode for this to work after renaming though.

Comment: The iOS file system is case-sensitive, but the Mac's file system is case-INsensitive.   So the simulator's disk can't tell the difference, but the device's disk can.

Comment: Pay attention to image names as well. Simulator case-insensitive, phone case sensitive. Spent an hour figuring out why an image wasn't loading until i figured it out

Comment: What about iPhone 5? I have used same convention(iphone5) but not working.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done automatically based on the name, no worries. The only problem is you'll need to switch your naming convention. MainView.xib will be your iPad xib and MainView~iphone.xib will be your iPhone xib. Then it should work perfectly for you and you don't have to do anything but alloc/init.

You can check out my other answer on this topic here: [iOS: Using device modifiers for loading xib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191472/ios-using-device-modifiers-for-loading-xib-files/5198133#5198133)