# How To Port an iPhone Application to the iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iphone app and I want to turn it into ipad app.
I created the xib_ipad, I used the UISwitchView and to the left is my root class, on the right I created a class that selects the choice, SelectView. I followed the guide http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad. But with my changes, does not work because the class SelectView (right), I create an object:

```
Select1 *one = [[Select1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Select1" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:one animated:YES];
```

but if I select it again or another, the views overlap. How can solve? Or how can select and load different class with different xib on the right part? I not use storyboard. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the [search function on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191472/ios-using-device-modifiers-for-loading-xib-files/5198133#5198133)?

Comment: yes i have search on site, but my question is different because i have make the porting, but i don't understand how manipulate different left controller with xib when i pressed on right menu.